# Como selecionar amostras em R

Tags: r

Como selecionar 100 amostras de tamanho `n = 10`, sem reposição, usando uma população de `N = 1000`?

Minha população:

```
set.seed(1234)
x <- rnorm(1000, mean = 100, sd = 20)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o replicate + sample com replace false:

```
a <- replicate(100, sample(x = x, size = 10, replace = F))
```

O replicate vai replicar o número de vezes que você estipular a função que estiver dentro dele.
Neste caso vai replicar 100 vezes a função sample.